# Integration tests with xUnit - does creating the client in the test constructor cause performance issues?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I have an `Asp.Net Core 6 Web Api` application.

I am trying to add Integration tests as described [here in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#customize-webapplicationfactory-1).

```
public class IndexPageTests : 
IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup>>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup> _factory;

    public IndexPageTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup> factory)
    {
       _factory = factory;
       _client = factory.CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = false
        });
    }
```

`xUnit` by design runs the test constructor before each test.

**My question is**: if we create the client before each test in the test class - like in the example - will this cause any performance issues to the tests? Will this cause the tests to run too slowly or consume too much memory?

Comment: What does "performance issues" mean?  It will create the client for each test.  You have to specify if that would be an issue for you.

Comment: @possum, exactly: what I mean is will creating the client before each test take too much time and resources? Will this cause the tests to run too slowly at some point?

Answer (score 0):

No, it will cause no performance issues in comparison to instantiating it elsewhere. The constructor will be ran before every test but that's just the same as how any class in C# works.

One caveat would be that if you try to do anything different with your client for a specific test (Swap services for example) then you'd probably have to create a new instance of it which wouldn't be ideal as you'd have two clients floating around. Although, if you're just using the client in the way you're showing in your question, then this won't cause issues.

Comment: There are ways to make it instantiate once before all tests, which would be faster than instantiating it each time.  Please read the documentation that addresses exactly this issue https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context

Comment: @possum -> the question was whether it would cause any performance issues, not ways to make it more performant. I'd massively advice against using class fixtures for this as if you were to want to change the client for a specific test then you wouldn't be able to do so.

Comment: "it will cause no performance issues in comparison to instantiating it elsewhere" is patently false given the information available.  "Advice" is not a question answer.

Comment: Question: "My question is: if we create the client before each test in the test class - like in the example - will this cause any performance issues to the tests". Answer: "No, it will cause no performance issues in comparison to instantiating it elsewhere".  Any performance improvement over instantiating once per class is pretty much negligible.

Comment: And advice is how people become better programmers. Teach a man to fish etc

Comment: You have misunderstood the purpose of this site.  It is to definitively answer questions, not offer your own opinions.

Comment: @possum "It is by programmers, for programmers, with the ultimate intent of collectively increasing the sum total of good programming knowledge in the world. No matter what programming language you use, or what operating system you call home. Better programming is our goal." source: https://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/

Comment: Yes, and there are rules and guidelines about what constitutes an answer and this site has normed on avoiding opinions.  If you have commentary it should be kept to the comments, not posted as an answer.

Comment: Guys, yes, I know the other way is to introduce a fixture and share it between tests, but as @scottdavidwalker mentioned this will make tests interdependent.

Comment: If there are no performance issues with the exmaple in MSDN, then I would prefer to go with this approach. Thank you for offering your opinions! I will wait a bit more and if there are no other opinions, I will choose @scottdavidwalker answer.